# Using SUM to find total amount in columns and then group by person

Tags: mysql

I have a list of amounts in my `transactions` table. I want to find out the total transaction amount for each `person_id` that has a total amount greater than `50`.

I was hoping this would work but it didn't:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM transactions WHERE person_id = p.id
) AS total_amount
FROM people AS p 
WHERE total_amount > 50
```

The only way I could get this to work was the following:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM transactions WHERE person_id = p.id
) AS total_amount
FROM people AS p 
WHERE (
    SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM transactions WHERE person_id = p.id
) > 50
```

.. which is super inefficient. Any suggestions on how I can format my query better?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not sure where and how I'd add that to my query to make it work. Do you have an example?

Comment: Yes, peterm provided it.

Comment: @Strawberry Ah yes thanks :) But unfortunately he removed the fact that I need the `people` table also included in the query as per my example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT person_id, SUM(amount)
  FROM transactions
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING SUM(amount) > 50
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb59c/1)**

**UPDATE:** `people` and `transactions` joined

```
SELECT t.person_id, p.name, SUM(t.amount) amount
  FROM transactions t JOIN
       people p ON t.person_id = p.id 
GROUP BY t.person_id, p.name
HAVING SUM(t.amount) > 50
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07a4b/2)**

Comment: Thanks for that! The only thing is I need to have the `people` table joined as I had in my example.

Comment: @BenSinclair You're welcome. See updated answer for a version with `JOIN`

Comment: Ah! So simple! Thank you so much, really appreciate you taking the time to help :)